# Why doesn't /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules exist on virtual machines?

Tags: linux, centos

CENTOS 5.9

I'm curious, why doesn't `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` exist on virtual machines with CentOS 5.9?  Is there an alternative file name for this when using a virtual machine?

Comment: Dunno, but it might be no longer necessary in the near future: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames

Comment: the file should be the same as in a non-vm-installation...

try looking at /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules which should generate these files.